# Process queue of API requests concurrently with

Tags: ruby, multithreading, mongodb, concurrency, message-queue

We currently have an API essentially taking two types of request: one to identify users details, and one to track events they perform. It currently processes all the logic within the request. We have two app boxes so it is possible for two identify requests with effectively the same data to be processed concurrently. Whilst performance wise this solution is fine at is current scale we are already seeing concurrency issues.

My question is: **How can we process a queue of api requests so that the requests related to one person are done in order within a single worker?**

Our stack is Ruby backed onto MongoDB, I'm more than happy to explore other technologies but obviously any solution that utilises our current stack is a plus.

I've thought about locking people records but don't know of a way to check for a lock, and if free, lock it in a single action, so that its not possible for two threads to check for a lock at the same time, think they both have it but actually only one has it.

My current idea (having very limited experience with message queues) is to queue requests and then use a consistent hash exchange to ensure requests for a person are always routed to the same worker. But reading the documentation it looks like a consistent hash exchange is really intend to help distribute tasks amongst workers rather than group them by a certain property.

Answer (score 1):

You could use redis for locking. [redis-objects](https://github.com/nateware/redis-objects#atomicity) has primitives for it. Here's a lower-level version: https://github.com/PatrickTulskie/redis-lock

It worked well for me in the past.

Comment: Thanks this exactly the kind of thing I was looking for in regard to locking

Answer (score 1):

Any specific hash based logic / distribution would automatically have property of routing to the same queue all the time, provided the key has not changed and the queues have not changed. So, provided same number of buckets and same key, it should be routed to same bucket.

From quick glance of consistent hash exchange, that principal is intact. The primary goal may be load distribution onto the queues, but the secondary property of unique/consistent route is conserved as part of it.

If load distribution was the only goal, there wouldn't have been a need for the key and the  load could have been distributed in round-robin basis as well.